# Is the Pendlay row the same as a bent-over barbell row?

Tags: barbell-rows

I'm trying to find the Pendlay row on exrx.net. Is it the same as the [barbell bent-over row](http://exrx.net/WeightExercises/BackGeneral/BBBentOverRow.html)?

Answer (score 2):

[Here's Glenn Pendlay](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZlRrIsoDpKg) explaining the difference between an unspecified "barbell row" and a stricter form barbell row or "Pendlay row":

Summary:

- Torso must be parellel to the ground to call it a Pendlay row
- The bar must return to the floor after every rep

Answer (score 1):

The only real difference is that the Pendlay row is a stricter version of the bent-over row.  **Important:** the assumption is that you are *not* doing what's referred to a "Yate's Row" where you body is at an angle to the ground instead of parallel with it.

Main distinction:

> Bar returns to the floor every rep.  (lifting from a dead stop)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is a fundamental difference between the Pendlay row and the bent-over barbell row. Neither of which, if you execute proper form, put your shoulders in a position to impinge.

The Pendlay Row has your torso, more or less, parallel with the ground and you pull the bar to your sternum (or just below) from the ground. You can pull a barbell to sternum without having your shoulders perpendicular to your torso. Your arms are typically between 45 and 75 degrees depending on your anthropometry and bio mechanics.

The Bent-over Row is where your torso is at 45 degrees, plus or minus a little, and you pull the barbell to your hips. Also, you continue holding the barbell during the exercise as opposed to starting each rep from the floor like the Pendlay Row.

The stabilizer muscles that are engaged are pretty much the same, the difference might be which ones have more stress on them. This is a result of the differences in how these similar exercises are executed.